# Помощь в js мемоизация

Tags: javascript

всем привет,как можно оптимизировать представленный ниже код, используя технику мемоизации.

```
function factorial(n) { 

return (n != 1) ? n * factorial(n - 1) : 1; 

} 

console.log(factorial(100));
```

Comment: Никак, он уже максимально оптимизирован

Comment: Ну да, максимум уже оптимизация, только вот если саму функцию `function factorial(n) {...}(100);` вызвать, но тогда какой будет смысл, если она сама себя будет вызывать да и только.

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее оптимальным для расчёта **одного** значения факториала будет простой цикл

```
function factorial(n) { 
  var f = 1
  for(var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
     f = f * i;
  }
   return f
}
```

Если же нужно будет много значений факториала, то мемоизация будет полезна. Для неизвестного диапазона я использовал Map, для ограниченного лучше будет массив

```
let map = new Map();

function factorial(n) { 
  f = map[n];
  if (!f) {
    f = (n != 1) ? n * factorial(n - 1) : 1;
    map[n] = f;
  }
  return f
}
```